# arguments and function call of LSTM in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Could anyone please explain me the below code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

input = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)

rnn = nn.LSTM(10,20,2)

output, (hn, cn) = rnn(input, (h0, c0))
print(input)
```

While calling rnn `rnn(input, (h0, c0))` we gave arguments h0 and c0 in parenthesis. What is it supposed to mean? if (h0, c0) represents a single value then what is that value and what is the third argument passed here?
However, in the  line `rnn = nn.LSTM(10,20,2)`  we are passing arguments in LSTM function without paranthesis.
Can anyone explain me how this function call is working?

Comment: Parenthesis in python are used to make tuples, you should read about it in the python documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment `rnn = nn.LSTM(10, 20, 2)` instanciates a new `nn.Module` using the [`nn.LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) class. It's first three arguments are `input_size` (here `10`), `hidden_size` (here `20`) and `num_layers` (here `2`).

On the other hand `rnn(input, (h0, c0))` corresponds to actually calling the class instance, `i.e.` running `__call__` which is roughly equivalent to the `forward` function of that module. The `__call__` method of `nn.LSTM` takes in two parameters: `input`  (shaped `(sequnce_length, batch_size, input_size)`, and a tuple of two tensors `(h_0, c_0)` (both shaped `(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)` *in the basic use case of `nn.LSTM`*)

Please refer to the PyTorch documentation whenever using builtins, you will find the exact definition of the parameters list (the arguments used to initialize the class instance) as well as the input/outputs specifications (whenever inferring with that said module).

---

You might be confused with the notation, here's a small example that could help:

- *tuple* as input:

  ```
  def fn1(x, p):
      a, b = p # unpack input
      return a*x + b

  >>> fn1(2, (3, 1))
  >>> 7
  ```
- *tuple* as output

  ```
  def fn2(x):
      return x, (3*x, x**2) # actually output is a tuple of int and tuple 

  >>> x, (a, b) = fn2(2) # unpacking
  (2, (6, 4))

  >>> x, a, b
  (2, 6, 4)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifications :)

Comment: Also, could you please explain how did you reach to this conclusion that__call__ is the one that is taking parameters? I read the source code https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#LSTM via this link and I cannot relate. Although, I understood your explanation quiet clearly. I want to know how did you figure it out? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Indeed `__call__` does not appear in [torch/nn/modules/rnn.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py), that's because the method is implemented in the super class `nn.Module`, and not the child class `nn.LSTM` (notice in the code you linked `class LSTM(RNNBase)` *L470*, and `class RNNBase(Module)` *L24*: the class hierarchy is `LSTM` < `RNNBase` < `Module`. The latter is the one implementing `__call__` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e2acce373fb9a60f402e437496eaff2195847b65/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1105). Let me know if that's clear for you!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `__call__` method is a special Python function that allows you to *call* the class instance (as you do with functions). In turn, if you have a class `A` defined along with a `__call__` definition, then you can call its instances: `a = A(); a()`. Having this particular method defined in the super class `nn.Module`, all `nn.Module` instances are callable objects...

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation :)